# RxSwift filter observable sequence and bind to tableview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, rx-swift

I have tableview in my iOS App

I have initialize the table using following code

```
var cnList : Observable<[CountryCode]>?
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    cnList = readJson()
        cnList?.bindTo(cTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "country_code_cell")) {
            _, countryCode, cell in
            if let countryCodeCell = cell as? CountryCodeTableViewCell {
                countryCodeCell.cNameLabel.text = countryCode.name
                countryCodeCell.cCodeLabel.text = countryCode.dial_code!
            }
        }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

now I have a text field and I want to filter the cList based on the text of that text field

I can print text as i press key

```
searchTextField.rx.text.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: {
            text in
            if text != nil && text != "" {
                // need to filter cnList and update tableview here i think but how ??
            }
        }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

but I am not sure how to filter `cnList` and update the `table view`

So how to do this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe like this:

First change `var cnList : Observable<[CountryCode]>?` to `var cnList : Variable<[CountryCode]>? = Variable([])`

then:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    cnList.value = readJson()
        cnList?.asObservable().bindTo(cTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "country_code_cell")) {
            _, countryCode, cell in
            if let countryCodeCell = cell as? CountryCodeTableViewCell {
                countryCodeCell.cNameLabel.text = countryCode.name
                countryCodeCell.cCodeLabel.text = countryCode.dial_code!
            }
        }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

then:

```
searchTextField.rx.text.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: {
            text in
            if text != nil && text != "" {
               self.cnList.value = self.cnList.value.filter({//some logic})
            }
        }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

I'm not sure, but it's should reload your table with new values.

Comment: i am converting `let list = [CountryCode]()` using `Observable.just(list)` by calling `readJson()` method. How to convert this `list` as `Variable<[CountryCode]>` ?

Comment: To be more functional you can improve the 2nd part:

`searchTextField.rx.text
            .filter{$0.characters.count > 0}
            .subscribe(onNext: { text in
                 self.cnList.value = self.cnList.value.filter({//some logic})
            })
            .addDisposableTo(bag)`